# When should you unlock a file after using NioLocker to lock it in your FileReadingMessageSource poller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using the common source code for setting up a directory poller in Spring Integration. The Poller uses NioLocker to lock and file, and per JavaDocs, I am responsible for unlocking the file using NioFileLocker.unlock(file).

My main questions are when should this take place and of course how?

My initial thought is after my job listener moves the file to a new directory. At this time I only know the file path name and do not have a handle for the File itself.

The directory poller code:

```
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "claimInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public FileReadingMessageSource claimPollingFileSource(){
        logger.debug("Setting up inbound channel adapter ===> claimInputChannel");

        CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter= new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("(?i).*_CLAIM_.*[.]txt"));
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(lastModifiedFilter());
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter());
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());

        FileReadingMessageSource pollDirectory = new FileReadingMessageSource();

        pollDirectory.setDirectory(new File(pollingDirectory));
        pollDirectory.setAutoCreateDirectory(false); 
        pollDirectory.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
        pollDirectory.setLocker(new NioFileLocker());           
        return pollDirectory;
    }
```

AfterJob code in the listener:

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    logger.debug("In afterJob routine");

    if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {    
        // check if directory exists
        File dir = new File(processedDirectory);
        if (dir.exists()) {
            Path sourcePath = Paths.get(jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("fileName"));
                String target = processedDirectory + "/" + sourcePath.getFileName();
            logger.debug("Moving processed file " + sourcePath.toString() + " to " + target);

            try {
                Files.move(sourcePath, Paths.get(target), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Something went wrong in moving file to processed directory.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("The " + processedDirectory + " does not exist.");
        }

    } else {
        logger.debug("Batch job is not yet complete.");
    }

}
```